# How to send all traffic over vpn connection ubuntu 20.04 for nordlayer VPN?

Tags: server, vpn

NordLayer VPN not sending all traffic over VPN connection ubuntu 20.04 for nordlayer VPN.

When I log in with nordlayer connect from the CLI, I am able to connect it and it will display the correct server address when I run nordlayer status command.

But When I go to the browser and check my IP address, it will always display my local IP address instead of VPN Address in Linux Ubuntu.

It's out of the box feature in Mac OS but I am not able to send all traffic through the browser in Linux.

Please let me know any solutions?

Comment: Silly question, but have you confirmed you're connecting to the VPN with the correct network adapter? Traffic should be routed correctly automatically ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this issue by installing **resolvconf**
The command is the,

```
sudo apt-get install resolvconf
```

Now Editing the file from the `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head`
Added entry in the DNS servers like in it :

```
nameserver 1.0.0.1
nameserver 1.1.1.1
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 2606:4700:4700::1001
nameserver 2606:4700:4700::1111
```

Now Just reboot the system using,

```
sudo reboot
```

Using this steps, I am able to fix it browsing issue of the VPN traffic.

Now When I go to Browser, Search what is my ip address and gives me the same IP address which is display on the VPN Server IP address.